# How can I instantiate PrintfArg

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to instantiate `PrintfArg` for a boxed string of mine. I'm following the example given in the doc but it doesn't work, as it can't find `formatArg'.
 Here is a simplified version

```
import Text.Printf
data MyString = MyString String

instance PrintfArg MyString where
    formatArg (MyString s) format = formatArg s format
```

I get the following error message

```
`formatArg' is not a (visible) method of class `PrintfArg'
```

I looked at the source of `Text.Printf` and indeed `formatArg` is not exported ?
Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug ?

Comment: Which version are you using? The source indicates that `formatArg` was added in version 4.7.0.0.

Comment: I'm using 4.6.0.1 which explain the problem. I think I got confused my the error message , saying 'method not visible' instead 'method non-existent'. I'm still not get used to check the version of the doc I'm reading

Comment: @lee: can you write an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using `ghc 7.6` with `base 4.6.0.1` where not only does `Text.Printf` [not export the class functions, but the class function is `toUPrintf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Text-Printf.html), not `formatArg`.

I don't know of a way to allow `printf` to print a custom type in `ghc 7.6`.

However, in `ghc 7.8`, it's all good. That uses `base 4.7.0.0`, where [`Text.Printf` does export `formatArg`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html), and your code works just fine.